# How can I get rid of elements containing exact symbols in the list? (python)

Tags: python, list, append

I have a list called "list", which consists of about 20K strings, and I need to remove from it elements which have "text": "" in it.

I'm creating a new clean list like this

```
clean_list = []

for i in list:
  if '"text": ""' in i == False:
    clean_list.append(i)
  print(i)
```

But elements don't append and clean_list is empty.
What can be the problem? Smth is wrong with the cycle.

How else can I get rid of some elements in the list?

Comment: Don't call your list `list`!

Comment: Have you tried: `if '"text": ""' not in i:`? And your list name is shadowing the builtin `list` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should not name variables with protected keywords like list.

For your use case you could use list comprehension:

```
clean_list = [string for string in list if '"text": ""' not in string]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if '"text": ""' in i == False:
```

Don't use that syntax.  The `i == False` is unnecessary (and looks awkward), and in this specific case, it actually causes the problem you're having.

Use this syntax instead:

```
if '"text": ""' not in i:
```

### If you want to know why this happens, keep reading.

This problem is due to *operator chaining*.

When you have an expression that contains two (or more) operators, such as this:

```
a < b < c
```

Python treats that expression as if you had typed this:

```
a < b and b < c
```

In your example, `in` and `==` are both operators, so Python treated your expression as though you had typed this:

```
if '"text": ""' in i and i == False:
```

The first part of that is true, but the second part is not.  So the expression as a whole is false.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this doesn't work is that the operators don't associate the way you think they do:

```
>>> '"text": ""' in "foo" == False
False
>>> ('"text": ""' in "foo") == False
True
```

Using `in ... == False` is awkward/un-Pythonic in any case; it's better to do the more natural `not in ...`:

```
>>> '"text": ""' not in "foo"
True
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using built-in named as variable names in Python.

```
s = 'This is a sample "text": "" and it should not have it.'
if r'"text": ""' in s:
    print("Found.")

The output will be `Found.`
```

Now, with the help of this you can use:

```
clean_list = [i for i in list if r'"text": ""' not in i]
# This just creates a new list if an item `i` is found not having the pattern '"text": ""'. The r' refers to raw strings and can be helpful when using a lot of symbols and characters.
```